# Is it dangerous to leave a node server listening for connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I'm starting to learn JavaScript, and am using node.js to set my computer up as a server. If I leave it listening for connections long-term, is this alone elevating the risk of my computer getting a virus/hacked? For example, I want to run a quotes server that friends could connect to by going to my computer's IP address on the open port and have it display a random quote in their browser. Would leaving this running in the background on my computer create a security risk?

Comment: It depends on whether there are exploitable bugs in your server code.

Comment: You can start with (1) making your server a bit more resilient to DoS attacks that aim to saturate it by taking away its limited capacity to respond to requests and (2) trying to make server defacing a bit more difficult. Assuming you use Express, the first good steps would be to use [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) and express-rate-limit, both require just a couple of lines of code. After that you are at the beginning of a very long journey because security is a vast topic. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64843006/12005425) you can find some extra steps (skip 1, 3, 7).